# Determine how many numbers in a string

Tags: java, split, numbers, words

I have an array of strings where I'm trying to find the number of words in each string. I understand how to find the total number of words, but it includes numbers too which I don't want. I have tried s[i].matches(".*\d+.*") but that just checks to see if there is at least one number in the string. I'm trying to find the total number of numbers (not digits). For example, one string is "IN CONGRESS, July 4, 1776." My code returns 5 words even though there are only 3 because it includes the 2 numbers.

Comment: You just need the correct regular expression that only matches what you want in the first place. If you were to post what you've tried, people can offer how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

total words - words with numbers should work. Use the following regex:

```
matches(".*[0-9].*")
```

Comment: I have tried that but `matches (".*[0-9].*")` is a boolean and only returns true or false. I need to then find out how many numbers there actually are in the string

Comment: You could use split(" ") on the String and then try matches on every elements. So you can use split(" ").length to get the total number of words/numbers and then substract how many matches the regex...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (String str : "IN CONGRESS, July 4, 1776.".split("(\\s+)(\\,)*(\\.)*"))
    {
        if (!str.matches("(.)*(\\d)(.)*"))
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("word "+count+":"+str);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total words:"+count);
}
```